# How to enable Moonlight?

Tags: firefox, mono, moonlight

Even after I've installed all the Mono packages, I am still asked to install Silverlight when I visit Silverlight-enabled web pages.

Even after I agreed to do this and installed the Moonlight Firefox extension from http://go-mono.com/moonlight/, nothing changed - Silverlight applets still don't work and ask to install Silverlight (directing to http://go-mono.com/moonlight/).

How do I finally install it?

The situation is the same in Ubuntu 10.10 and Xubuntu 11.04.

Comment: What applets?. Silverligth only supports old versions of silverlight, it's currently one major version behind, and likely it'll be two in the next months, when Silverlight 4 is out of beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install [**moonlight-plugin-mozilla**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/moonlight-plugin-mozilla) [image: Install moonlight-plugin-mozilla]
- Restart firefox

Comment: This is outdated as of Dec 2012 and Ubuntu 12.10. The package is not part of the repositories anymore. Fortunately, a manual installation from here http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/ works (see answer by user14850) with Ubuntu 12.10/Firefox 17 (at least).

Answer (score 2):

This version at moonlight site is beta, but it worked for me.

http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx

And it shall work according to Mozilla

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Using%20the%20Silverlight%20plugin%20with%20Firefox

Answer (score 0):

[For Google Chrome here is the plugin](http://go-mono.com/moonlight/downloads/2.3.0.1/novell-moonlight-2.3.0.1-i586.crx)